# Reading Large json.gz files crashes kernel

Tags: memory-management, jupyter-notebook, kernel, dask

I have a dataset that's 7GB worth of data. I am reading it as follows:

`path = direc + '2018-01-*.*'
ddf = dd.read_json(path,blocksize=None)`

I used this method because reading it through pandas seemed to keep crashing my kernel and using up my local memory - I am running this on my machine.

I need to do a bunch of analysis, but any command seems to crash the kernel, if im saving to parquet, or even doing a count or dropping duplicates.

Any suggestions on how I can run commands/manipulate this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see everything that you're doing is fine.  Dask shouldn't ever crash the kernel, the worst that might happen in a situation like this is that you run out of memory.

So you may have to figure out how to provide more information concisely to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)